# Print largest and smallest number in python

Tags: python

I am trying to write a program that repeatedly prompts a user for integer numbers until the user enters 'done'. Once 'done' is entered, print out the largest and smallest of the numbers. If the user enters anything other than a valid number catch it with a try/except and put out an appropriate message and ignore the number.

I am having problem in printing the largest and smallest number. Its printing incorrect number by the approach below:

```
largest = None
smallest = None
list1 = []
while True:
    num = input("Enter a number: ")
    if num == "done" : break
    try:
        val = int(num)
        if int(num):
            list1.append(num)
    except:
        print("Invalid input") 
print("Maximum is " + max(list1))
print("Minimum is " + min(list1))
```

I am entering numbers as 7, 2, bob, 10, and 4.

Its printing output as: 
Invalid input
Maximum is 7 
Minimum is 10

While the output I am looking for is:
Invalid input
Maximum is 10
Minimum is 2

Comment: Do you want to treat the value of `0` special? Right now your logic (when syntax is fixed) ignores 0 because `if 0` evaluates to `False`.

Comment: Also you can do this more efficiently by keeping track of the smallest and largest as you get new numbers. No need for a `list`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must append `int` in your list, not `str`.

Change this:

```
if int(num):
    list1.append(num)
```

to one of the following: (the `if int(num)` is unnecessary.)

```
list1.append(int(num))
```

or

```
list1.append(val)
```

You must also convert to string before concatenating in the print statement:

```
print("Maximum is " + str(max(list1)))
print("Minimum is " + str(min(list1)))
```

With the modifications, your program should look like this:

```
largest = None
smallest = None
list1 = []
while True:
    num = input("Enter a number: ")
    if num == "done" : break
    try:
        val = int(num)
        list1.append(val)
    except ValueError:         # it is always better to specify what type of error you are expecting to catch
        print("Invalid input") 
print("Maximum is " + str(max(list1)))
print("Minimum is " + str(min(list1)))
```

Comment: Its giving me error now: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'int' objects

Comment: Yes sorry, you must convert back to string to concatenate before printing (see update in answer)

Answer (score 2):

without using a list, you need Two value to keep track of max and min value of user input. use try and except to handle case when user enter a non numerical input other than 'done'.

Fast and better approach than using a list store value,sort data and and then get the final result

```
import sys

min_val = sys.maxsize
max_val = -sys.maxsize-1

flag = True
while flag:
    user_input = input()
    if user_input == 'done':
        flag = False
    else:
        try:
            user_input = int(user_input)
            if user_input>max_val:
                max_val = user_input
            if user_input<min_val:
                min_val = user_input
        except ValueError:
            print('Enter a Valid Number')



print('Maximum Value is {}'.format(max_val))
print('Minimum value is {}'.format(min_val))
```

Answer (score 0):

You converted `num` to an int and stored it in `val`, but then you ignored that and inserted the original, `num`, in your list. Since it is a string, Python will take the minimum sorted alphabetically, so "10" is less than "2".

To fix it you just need to insert `val` in your list instead.

```
    val = int(num)
    if val:
        list1.append(val)
```

Comment: Why keep the `if val`?

Comment: Its still giving me the same output.